# Изменение количества товаров корзине data-toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, django

Подскажите как при изменении количества товара в корзине менять  переменную  data-toggle в шаблоне на Active или Inactive

html

```
 <div class="cart" data-toggle="inactive">
      <div class="label">
        <i class="ion-bag"></i>  {{request.session.cart|length}}
      </div>

      <div class="overlay"></div>

      <div class="window">
        <div class="title">
          <button type="button" class="close"><i class="ion-android-close"></i></button>
          <h4>Корзина</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="content">

          {%if request.session.cart.items %}
          {% for key,value in request.session.cart.items %}
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="{{value.image}}" alt="{{value.name}}"/>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">{{value.name}}</h4>
              <label>{{value.category}}</label>
              <p class="price">Всего ${{ value.price|multiply:value.quantity }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                  <a href="{% url 'item_decrement' value.product_id %}"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" data-action="minus"><i class="ion-minus-round"></i></button></a>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Qty" value=" {{value.quantity}} " readonly="">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <a href="{% url 'item_increment' value.product_id %}">  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" data-action="plus"><i class="ion-plus-round"></i></button></a>
                </span>
              </div><!-- /input-group -->
              <a href="{% url 'item_clear' value.product_id %}"></i> Удалить </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          {%else%}
            <h3> Корзина пуста </h3> 
          {%endif%}
      

        </div>
```

views.py

```
def item_increment(request, id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    cart.add(product=product)
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','redirect_if_referer_not_found'))
```